# Rails – creating an efficient priority method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, destroy

I have 10 tasks and an integer priority column. Each task is given a number 1 through 10 – 1 being the most important, and 10 being the least. Let's say I accomplish task number 4 (and destroy it after completion), how can I make tasks 5 through 10 adjust to 4 through 9?

I am trying to decide on the best way to do this. I am thinking the code would follow this logic:

after destroy (of let's say task 4), the hash of Tasks is counted and then updated – with each task receiving it's new priority integer based on its index in the hash.

How would I begin writing this code and is my logic in the first place sound?

Comment: Do you need to be able to add items anywhere in the list or is it assumed the last item is the least important?

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question, but as it sands, it's not a good fit for how we do things at Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow works best for specific, technical questions that have a "right answer"... this is more of a "how do I go about designing this?" question. We normally expect you to have a go at these sorts of things yourself first, then come back to us when you get stuck on a specific error. if you need help designing your code, you'll need to find somebody that has time to help you with that, e.g. ask your local ruby users group.

Answer (score 2):

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

after_destroy :update_priority

def update_priority

```
Task.all.each_with_index { |n, i| n.update_attribute(:priority, i+1) }
```

end

end

Explanation: on the destroy action (when I complete a tasks and get rid of it), destroy calls the update_priority method. This does an index of the tasks in the hash, updates all the priority attributes, and seeing as index starts at 0, and my priorities start at 1, I just add 1 to every updated attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to think about here.

First, it sounds like these tasks are stored in the DB. You may want to think about a way to store them in an array (in memory) rather than having them in the DB. Doing these kinds of queueing tasks within an array is much more efficient than having to read and write to the DB.

If the structure is such that they are in the DB, you may want to do a single read operation from the DB to write your 10 tasks (to use your example) to an array. Do your data handling (sorting, queuing, deleting) in the array, then write back to the DB when you are done.

Here is a good primer on Stacks and Queues in Ruby. Good luck!

https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/33-advanced-arrays/lessons/86-stacks-and-queues

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help! I figured out a way to do it! My solution works very well for me, but it definitely isn't the only way to do it or even the best way. Let me know what you think – I put the solution below:

Comment: Looks good dude! Nice work.